# What's the best way of using Case When Statement for 100 or more products

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my table "sellers"

```
+------------+---------+----------+
| Seller_ID  | Product |  Units   |
+------------+---------+----------+
| Seller_123 |   A1    |   10     |
| Seller_123 |   B2    |   20     |
| Seller_123 |   C3    |   70     |
+------------+---------+----------+
```

From here you can see that this "Seller_123" main product group is C3 because his units focus mostly in C3 with 70 units. Here is what I am trying to achieve

```
+------------+-------------+
| Seller_ID  | Main_Product| 
+------------+-------------+
| Seller_123 |      C3     |  
+------------+-------------+
```

Here is my current SQL query

```
WITH TEMP
AS (
    SELECT Seller_ID
        ,SUM(CASE 
                WHEN Product = 'A1'
                    THEN Units
                END) AS A1_Units
        ,SUM(CASE 
                WHEN Product = 'B2'
                    THEN Units
                END) AS B2_Units
        ,SUM(CASE 
                WHEN Product = 'C3'
                    THEN Units
                END) AS C3_Units
    FROM sellers
    GROUP BY Seller_ID

    )
SELECT Seller_ID
    ,CASE 
        WHEN A1_Units > B2_Units
            AND A1_Units > C3_Units
            THEN A1
        WHEN B2_Units > A1_Units
            AND B2_Units > C3_Units
            THEN B2
        WHEN C3_Units > A1_Units
            AND C3_Units > B2_Units
            THEN C3
        END AS Main_Product
FROM TEMP
```

what is a better way of doing this? What if I have 100 products, I cannot do case when in that case?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: From your query, it seems like you want to get MAX(A1,B2,C3) AS Main_Product. Am i right?

Comment: Yes it is. But I dont want to have to a column for each of them

Comment: Ok. you can do this.
Idea: fetch data from 3 different columns A3_Units, B3_Units and C3_Units in to one column and then get the maximum.
Does this make any sense?

Comment: Yes. it makes sense. I am going to implement the answer suggested below tomorrow also. thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    SELECT  S1.SELLER_ID, S1.PRODUCT AS MAIN_PRODUCT 
    FROM SELLER S1,
    (SELECT SELLER_ID, MAX(UNITS) AS MAX_UNIT FROM SELLER
    GROUP BY SELLER_ID) S2
    WHERE S1.SELLER_ID = S2.SELLER_ID
    AND S1.UNITS=S2.MAX_UNIT
```

The tables is like below.

```
    select * from SELLER;

    Seller_ID   Product Units
    Seller_123   A1     10
    Seller_123   B2     20
    Seller_123   C3     70
    Seller_456   D1     10
    Seller_456   E2     20
```

Upon running the given select statement, you will get data like below

```
    SELECT  S1.SELLER_ID, S1.PRODUCT AS MAIN_PRODUCT 
    FROM SELLER S1,
    (SELECT SELLER_ID, MAX(UNITS) AS MAX_UNIT FROM SELLER
    GROUP BY SELLER_ID) S2
    WHERE S1.SELLER_ID = S2.SELLER_ID
    AND S1.UNITS=S2.MAX_UNIT


    SELLER_ID   MAIN_PRODUCT
    Seller_456   E2
    Seller_123   C3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this tomorrow

Comment: Np. And if the answer returns the result the way you want, then please Accept it by clicking the 'tick' on the left of the answer. 
All the best.

Answer (score 2):

First calculate all sales for each product, then see which one is the max. Then join both.

Take note if two products are tie, both will appear.

You didnt say if want result for all `Seller_ID` or just one in particular
This is for all sellers.

```
WITH Sales as (
    SELECT 
        Seller_ID, Product, SUM(Units) AS Total        
    FROM 
        sellers
    GROUP BY 
        Seller_ID, Product
), 
Focus as  (
    SELECT Seller_ID, MAX(Total) Total
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY Seller_ID
)   
SELECT *
FROM Sales
Inner Join Focus 
    ON  Sales.Total = Focus.Total
    and Sales.Seller_ID = Focus.Seller_ID
```

Comment: This answer looks great. Let me try this tomorrow